# Javascript redirect timeout form submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with connecting the form to the timeout array. I want it to timeout for 5000ms and display DELAY before it submits.

HTML

```
<form name="thisform" action="" method="get" onsubmit="window.open('http://www.mydomain.com/'+document.thisform.url.value,'_self');return false;">
   <input name="url" type="text" />
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$('thisform').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds

    $("<p>Delay...</p>").appendTo("body");
});
```

Comment: What is the issue you're experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You are using a wrong selector.

Change the `$('thisform')` to `$('form[name="thisform"]')`. Your final code should look like:

```
$('form[name="thisform"]').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds

    $("<p>Delay...</p>").appendTo("body");
});
```

**Explanation**

The selector `$('thisform')` will select any tag like `<thisform>`. So, since you have a form, with a `name` as `thisform`, you need to use a selector like `$('form[name="thisform"]')`. Hope you get it.

Comment: dot is for `class`, not `name`

Comment: Oops... Updating the question.

Comment: @charlietfl http://jsfiddle.net/HZ7Yx/5/ its not working. any reason why?

Comment: @SophieRhodes You haven't included jQuery (see the first drop-down menu on top left). Keep the JavaScript error console open, much easier to debug these things.

Comment: @SophieRhodes You didn't include jQuery! :P Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/HZ7Yx/6/